# how do I fetch a certain part out of an database?

Tags: php, database, pdo

Is there an way to only fetch the "vraag_naam"  out of "vragen_wrts"?

```
    $servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "nl_naar_eng";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT vraag_naam, vraag_antwoord FROM vragen_wrts");
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$words = $stmt->fetchAll();
//$engels = $words["vraag_antwoord"];
//var_dump($words ["vraag_naam"]);
```

I've put tries that didn't work in //

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchAll()` will returns an array. you might want to iterate this one.

In example :

```
$words = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($words as $word)
    var_dump($word["vraag_naam"]);
//                ^---------------notice the missing s
```

Comment: This is so unnecesary especially when you want only 1 row

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile he never stated he needs only 1 row, but 1 col

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) instead of `fetchall()`.

`fetch()` which fetches a row from a result set associated with a PDOStatement object.

```
<?php

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "nl_naar_eng";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$words = $conn->query("SELECT vraag_naam, vraag_antwoord FROM vragen_wrts")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $words["vraag_naam"];
?>
```

Update :

If you only need to fetch 1 row then only selected that row and use fetchColumn() instead.

```
<?php

$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "nl_naar_eng";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$words = $conn->query("SELECT vraag_naam FROM vragen_wrts")->fetchColumn();

echo $words["vraag_naam"];
?>
```

Comment: fetch() is the best method for this, however, the query still returns n number of pointless rows, would update SQL to LIMIT 1 in this case too. +1 for answer though

Comment: @Jaquarh yhea, will update